# Want to show first three rss news only before expanding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the code that able to expand and reduce when user click on the 'plus' or 'minus' sign. However, I want to shows

1. Before expand, shows **first three rss news**. After expand, shows all rss news.
2. I want to shows text 'More' and 'Less' besides the ion-plus and ion-minus

before expand:

[image: this picture]

after expand:

[image: this picture]

This is my code:

**html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider">News</div>
  <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-if='showMoreNews'ng-repeat="story in stockNews| orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openNews(story.link)">
    <h2>{{story.title || ''}}</h2>
    <h6>{{story.pubDate | characters:17:false:false || 'N/A'}}</h6>
    <p ng-if="story.description.length > 0">{{story.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
    <!-- <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> -->
  </a>
  <div ng-click="toggleNews()" <i class="icon" ng-class="showMoreNews ? 'ion-android-remove-circle assertive' : 'ion-android-add-circle positive'"></i><i class="padding" ng-class="showMoreNews ? 'Less' : 'More'"></i></div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
  $scope.showMoreNews = false;
    $scope.toggleNews = function(){
      $scope.showMoreNews = !$scope.showMoreNews;
    };
```

Please advice how to make it to work as the desirable result?

**UPDATES:**

with suggeston by @SAJ
Here is the code with showNews and showMoreNews above.
It shows 3 columns list  but nothing in the rss news items Just a blank list

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dmag.png

html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider">News</div>
  <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-if='showNews($index)' ng-repeat="story in stockNews| orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openNews(story.link)">
    <div ng-if='showMoreNews'>
    <h2>{{story.title || ''}}</h2>
    <h6>{{story.pubDate | characters:17:false:false || 'N/A'}}</h6>
    <p ng-if="story.description.length > 0">{{story.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
  </div>
    <!-- <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> -->
  </a>
  <div ng-click="toggleNews()" <i class="icon" ng-class="showMoreNews ? 'ion-android-remove-circle assertive' : 'ion-android-add-circle positive'"></i><i class="padding" ng-class="showMoreNews ? 'Less' : 'More'"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div block inside your ng-repeat element and add a logic to hide the item if the index of the looping item is greater than 2. Those will be visible when $scope.showMoreNews is true. You can use $index in the html to get the index of the looping item inside a ng-repeat

> So your html will look like this

```
<a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="story in stockNews | orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openNews(story.link)">
  <div ng-if='showNews($index)' >
      <h2>{{story.title || ''}}</h2>
      <h6>{{story.pubDate | characters:17:false:false || 'N/A'}}</h6>
      <p ng-if="story.description.length > 0">{{story.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

> And in your controller

```
    $scope.showNews = function(index){
         return index <= 2 || $scope.showMoreNews
        };
```

Comment: can you try log and check whether the index is getting correctly in the showNews method?

Comment: `console.log($scope.showNews);` in angularjs and `<div id="console-log"></div>` unable to show errors

Comment: Please refer the updates above. I reverse the location of `ng-if'ShowNews'` and `ng-if='showMoreNews'`. It gets 3 lists but it is empty. It only shown when expand it. Any idea?

Comment: Actually you don't require <div ng-if='showMoreNews'>. I have updated my answer, I didn't notice the ng-if statement in the <a> element, you can remove that.

Comment: It will shows all the rss news just like before. It is unable to shows 3 items. Also, how do it function to expand 3 rss news to 10  news without `ng-if =showMoreNews`?

Comment: Here the showNews function is the one who determines whether to show the news or not by checking the index. If the index of the news is <= 2 it will return true else it will return false. So for the 4th news onwards the function will return false and it should n't be showing the data. Did you check whether the index value is coming correctly by logging it?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your menaing. The rss news always contains 10 items inside. I want to show first 3 initially. Click expand, it will show all 10 items. Your code is assumed if the rss news contains item less than 3, shown 3 items, more than 3, which is false, will not shown any rss news?

Comment: The code I shown is supposed to show first 3 items only initially and when user clicks the show more it will show other 7 items. Here the $index is the index of the item in the array. So in first iteration of ng-repeat $index will be 1 and in next iteration it will be 2 and so on. So for first 3 iteration the ng-if function output will be true and data will be shown. From 4th iteration onwards ng-if will be false and those data won't show. 
When user clicks the view more button $scope.showMoreNews variable will be true and hence all the news will be visible..